# Spring MVC, Thymleaf on ajax call return new HTML page

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am new to thymeleaf. I am planning to implement simple web application with html pages. My landing page controller url is below which returns index.html page

```
@RequestMapping("/index")
public String index() {
    return "index";
}
```

I have a button in index.html page which triggers below controller call and want to return a different onclick.html HTML page

```
@RequestMapping("/web/onclick/{onclickvar}")
public String onclick(Model model, @PathVariable("onclickvar") String onclickvar) {
//do something with onclickvar
    return "onclick";
}
```

Can anybody provide sample code please.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking... does that second controller not return "onclick.html"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anchor link instead of a button to do the same.

```
<a href="onclick.html" th:href="@{/web/onclick/${someValueForClickvar}">Click here to go to onclick.html</a>
```

The above link will hit the controller and `@PathVariable("onclickvar") String onclickvar` should have the value `"someValueForClickvar"`.

Note : note that here `/web/onclick/${someValueForClickvar}` is the value which you want to pass as a path variable so change the variable name accordigly.